# Dradis Install Apt Issue Git Checkout

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux

I tried to install *kali-full*:

```
sudo apt-get install kali-linux-full
```

But it needed *dradis*, so i executed:

```
sudo apt-get install dradis
```

But the installation failed on:

```
The git source https://github.com/dradis/dradis-plugins.git is not yet checked out. 
Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

**4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux**

After in */usr/lib/dradis* executing *bundle install*:

```
Bundle complete! 81 Gemfile dependencies, 125 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups assets, development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into /usr/lib/dradis.
```

And in the log i can find:

> ...
>
> Using dradis-plugins 3.6.0 from https://github.com/dradis/dradis-plugins.git (at master@fba8ff8)
>
> ...

but the error is always the same trying to install.

Comment: You tried to install `kali-linux-full` *where*? On what OS? Are you running Kali? Ubuntu? Debian? Something else? And what happened when you ran the command your error message tells you to run? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon sorry, just edited.

Comment: Yes, *and what happened when you ran the command your error message tells you to run?*